# how much memory should be occupied by a valid SIP request?and how to monitor it before forwording to server?

Tags: memory, request, sip

I am gonna do a project related to intrusion detection in which i need to monitor the load on memory by a SIP request before forwarding it to server in order to determine that the specific request is valid(not a flooding attack on server)and will not cause DOS?Any information related to memory monitoring of the incoming request,algorithms and related articles will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is normally described as a [Session border controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_border_controller).

As for the normal packet size, SIP normally uses UDP so its normal packet is is normally under 1400 bytes.  If it exceeds this (and it can with a large SDP payload) then it normally (auto) switches over to TCP.

Most SIP packets tho are pretty small on average.